# Show that $A + A^{-1} \geq 2I$ for $A > 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

For a positive matrix $A$.  Here, we assume that all positive matrices are self-adjoint.  Show that 
\begin{align}
A + A^{-1} \geq 2I.
\end{align}

Here, $A≥0$ means that A is self-adjoint and for all $x∈ℂn,⟨Ax,x⟩≥0.$

Comment: What does $A\ge B$ mean for matrices? Is it entrywise?

Comment: It means that $a_{ij}\ge b_{ij }$ for all $i,j$

Comment: It probably means that $\forall i,j, \quad A_{i,j}=B_{i,j}$

Comment: Assume positive means positive definite symmetric matrix, then $A + A^{-1} \ge 2I$ because $(A + A^{-1}) - 2I = (A^{1/2} - A^{-1/2})^2$ is the square of a symmetric matrix.

Comment: $A \ge B$ means that $A - B$ is positive semi-definite, i.e. that $\langle x, (A - B)x \rangle \ge 0$ for all vectors $x$.

Comment: In my experience matrix positivy is defined entry wise.

Comment: Why do you assume that positive matrices are self adjoint?

Comment: @GitGud That's far from standard, though: I've often seen $A>0$ for $A$ positive-definite.

Comment: @user7530 I have, especially in TeX context, seen
$$A \succ 0$$
for positive definity and
$$A > 0$$
for entrywise positivity.

Comment: In Roger Horn's book **Matrix Analysis**, he defines a positive matrix exactly as I have above: entrywise. He also defines the ordering exactly as I have: entrywise. That is all there is to it.

Comment: @Vladhagen:  all there is to it from Roger Horn's point of view!

Comment: The statement is false if $A > 0$ means its entries are positive. eg. take $A$ as $\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @achillehui:  Right!

Comment: Wow.  Let this get away from me.  Thanks for all the hearty debate, but here, $A \geq 0$ means that $A$ is self-adjoint and for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}, \; \langle Ax,x \rangle \geq 0$.$

Comment: @DRich:  Your last comment is a very clear statement of what you mean by $A \ge 0$.  If you edited your question so that it was that clear, I suspect you might increase your chances of it being re-opened, which incidentally is something I voted for.  And for the question itself.  So best of luck with this; no promises however: I can't speak for/control my colleagues here on MSE.  Regards, RKL.

Comment: It seems to have been effectively answered by @voldemort.  I will, however edit it so it is easy to read as stated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$A \geq 0$ means $\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq 0$. $A \geq B$ means $A-B \geq 0$ which translates to $\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq \langle Bx,x \rangle$.

Now for your problem we need to show $A+A^{-1} \geq 2I$.

So, we need to show $\langle A+A^{-1}x,x \rangle \geq 2 \langle x,x\rangle =2 \lVert x\rVert^2$.

Now, $A$ ,$A^{-1}$ are self adjoint, and commute, and hence can be simultaneously diagonalised.

So, let $A=diag(\lambda_1,...\lambda_n)$.
Then, $A^{-1}=diag(1/\lambda_1,...1/\lambda_n)$. Now, $\lambda_i$ is postive, as $A$ is a positive matrix. For a postive number $a$ we always hve $a+1/a \geq 2$. Hence your result follows.

Comment: I see you adopted the notation $A > 0$ for $A$ positive definite! +1, and not just for that!

Comment: Thanks so much!  Really was having a rough one with this during qual prep.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a diagonalization of $A$.

This is also a diagonalization of $A + A^{-1}$.
 You are then reduced to show that
$$
a + \frac 1{a} \ge 2
$$for each (potential eigenvalue) $a>0$.

The function $$
f(a) =  a + \frac 1{a}
$$ is minimum when $a=1$ and then the minimum is $2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$A+A^{-1} -2 I =A^{-1}(A^2+ I -2A)= A^{-1}(A-I)^2 $$
and both $A^{-1}$ and $(A-I)^2$ are positive-definite.

Comment: Very nice, very clean, very deft!  Very +1